# Quotation marks

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Should the quotation marks ("I") be used in the following sentence?:

> In scientific papers, singular personal pronoun "I" tends to be replaced by a plural form.

For my opinion, it's correct. What do you think about it?

Comment: (1) _the_ singular personal pronoun (2) _In_ my opinion. You could use brackets as well when introducing the singular personal pronoun ("I").

Comment: When referring to words *qua* words in a sentence it is customary to use quotation marks or italics.

Comment: https://www.enago.com/academy/we-vs-they-using-first-or-third-person-in-a-research-paper/